# Bootstrap - How to make Navbar buttons equal width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap with a navbar at the top. In the navbar, I have five buttons that looks as follows:

[image]

The Razor code for one of the buttons looks like this (the other four are about the same):

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius: 20px;">Sign up<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

I'd like to make the buttons all the same width but I can't seem to find the CSS that controls this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you have to figure out the right CSS selector (Chrome Inspect Element can help here). I suspect these are probably nested in a DIV or UL with a .nav class or whatever. Then you can just set the 'width' property in your style.css (or whatever your stylesheet is named) file, or between style tags in your HTML.

If you can edit the HTML just add a class like "nav-btn" to each button you want to modify.

So, for example, if you added that here's what it would look like...

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary btn-lg nav-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius: 20px;">Sign up<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-btn {
  width: 50px; //or whatever width/units you like that fits everything
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the CSS within your HTML file with the `<style>` tag:

```
<style>
    .nav-btn {
      width: 50px; //or whatever width/units you like that fits everything
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 25%;
```

(These are more characters to meet minimum answer length requirements)

Comment: Don't forget the space between the buttons.

Comment: He's gonna have to work out any padding issues himself. The question just says asks for same width.